# Generating map tiles (dynamically?) from SQL/CSV data

Tags: google-maps, maps, leaflet, tile, wms

here's what I have:

- SQL table/CSV file with "tile XYZ" coordinates (web mercator tile coordinates) and "data/color"

  `X    Y   Z    Color
  13   13   5    yellow
  13   14   5    green
  13   14   5    red
  ...`
- data structure very easy, no fancy stuff needed, I can draw the pngs by code.
- amount of data is large, i.e. worldwide tiled, say zoomlevel 15

what I want:

- png tiles
- underlying data should not be accessible
- show the png tiles as a webpage map with help of leaflet/google maps api

problem/question:

- too much data to generate ALL tiles worldwide before (takes days)
- I was therefore thinking about a dynamic caching/tile creation algorithm (maybe create zoomlevel 0-9 before, higher zoom levels created dynamically)
- it seems there are many tools out there (TileMill, TileStache, ArcGIS Server, etc) but all of them seem to have a high learning curve or are meant for more complex tasks.
- is there a way to run a lean server that exactly fits my needs? Maybe with a php script that queries the database, draws the png and feeds that to the map on-demand? how would that work exactly? What would be a clever solution?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through a somewhat similar problem: having the tile indexes, return the points of a table that fell into the corresponding bounding box.

**Backend**

Since I was using PostgreSQL + PostGIS as a BBDD, I used a function that's defined in [Peter Warden's PostGIS2Gmap](https://github.com/petewarden/postgis2gmap) repo.

```
bounds_for_tile_indices(lat_index float8, lon_index float8, zoom_level int)
```

> This takes latitude and longitude coordinates for a tile, and a zoom
>   level, and returns a geography object containing the bounding box for
>   that tile. I mainly use this for limiting queries on geographic data
>   to a particular tile, eg;

```
SELECT * FROM checkins WHERE ST_Intersects(lonlat, bounds_for_tile_indices(6, 2, 4);
```

Now, for your use case, you might not have every possible tile already stored into a given table, but you can still use said function to determine the bounding box of a given tile coords:

```
SELECT Box2D(bounds_for_tile_indices(13, 14, 5)::geometry);
```

Which returns

```
BOX(-22.5 21.9430434618232,-11.25 31.9521604783552)
```

Please note that I'm explicitly casting the output of `bounds_for_tile_indices` as a geometry, since its native output is a geography and you cannot apply Box2D over a geography.

**Since you say you'll have a table of tile coordinates instead of geometries, the former method might be overkill**.

You probably just need to query your table for the given x/y/x combination, get the color you need, and then generate a 256x256px image of the given color, using [imagefill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php). Quoting the docs example:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

// sets background to red
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);
```

Or, keep a limited collection of 256x256px PNG files, then use the color you got from the query to build the path to the right image, and then use [imagecreatefrompng](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) to create the final result you'll send to the front with the proper image header to be treated as PNG.

As you see, drawing plain colored tiles is fairly easy, but I went through the first part just because I believe those tiles aren't as plain as in your question.

**Frontend**

In the front, you just need to declare a custom map type (in particular, for your use case a `google.maps.ImageMapType`)

```
var myTilesMap = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
            return "/my_backend/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + "/" + zoom;
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        name: "MyTiles"
    });

map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, myTilesMap);
```